# updating image in upload folder and image path in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to update images in my upload folder and mysql database the file uploads giving the file name 0.jpg instead of the normal persons id 13.jpg and does not update in mysql database, here is my snippet below what am i doing wrong?

```
$pic = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_FILES['photo']['name']));



   //This gets all the other information from the form

 $pic=($_FILES['photo']['name']);

    $file = $_FILES['photo']['name']; // Get the name of the file (including file extension).
    $ext = substr($file, strpos($file,'.'), strlen($file)-1);
    if(!in_array($ext,$allowed_filetypes))//check if file type is allowed
        die('The file extension you attempted to upload is not allowed.'); //not allowed
    if(filesize($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name']) > $max_filesize) //check that filesize is less than 50MB
        die ('The file you attempted to upload is too large, compress it below 50MB.');


    // Connects to your Database
     mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die(mysql_error()) ;
     mysql_select_db("office") or die(mysql_error()) ;

    //Writes the information to the 



  $target = "images/" .mysql_insert_id() . $ext; 

  $staff_id = mysql_insert_id();
  $new_file_name = mysql_insert_id() . $ext;


  //I removed ,photo='$target' to display only id as picture name
  mysql_query("UPDATE development SET photo='$new_file_name' WHERE staff_id=$staff_id");


//Writes the file to the server
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target))
{

 //Tells you if its all ok
  echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory";
}
else {

//Gives and error if its not
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
}
?>
```

Comment: you're calling `mysql_insert_id()` without ever having done an insert, so you get back a boolean false/0 value.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

`$staff_id = mysql_insert_id();`
  `$new_file_name = mysql_insert_id() . $ext;`

`//I removed ,photo='$target' to display only id as picture name
  mysql_query("UPDATE development SET photo='$new_file_name' WHERE staff_id=$staff_id");`

do something like thus

```
mysql_query ("INSERT INTO development (photo) VALUES ( '".$new_file_name."' )");    
//first insert  
$staff_id = mysql_insert_id() ;     
// then get the id of the record you've just inserted
```

Comment: Careful. development might not be the users/persons table. If it isn't, you'll be getting the primary key of the development instead of the user.

Comment: and probably the whole architecture is wrong. I guess you need a table of uploaded files and a table of people (staff). Each user can upload many images.

So you first need to insert a new image to a table of images together with the id of the user who uploaded it (to get this id of the user you might need another query or you have it in the session). Then, you get the id of the just uploaded image and do whatever you need to do with it, for example, store it in the table of users, if you have there something like "last submitted image" field.

Comment: When i inserted before updating it creates a new record in the database instead of updating

Comment: No, it does not. See the docs: Retrieves the ID generated for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the previous query (usually INSERT).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you're using the mysql_* functions, which are deprecated as of 5.5.

Secondly, you need to look at the manual page for [mysql_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-insert-id.php). Quote:

> Retrieves the ID generated for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the
>   previous query (usually INSERT).

This means that you can only call mysql_insert_id() AFTER you've inserted data into or updated your users/persons table. In your case, however, it seems as though you already have the ID of the person stored in the variable `$staff_id`, so you probably don't even need to use mysql_insert_id. Would this not work instead?

```
$target = "images/" . $staff_id . $ext;
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it gives me Notice: Undefined variable: staff_id